# check if coordinates are changed in picturebox click and return a value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, coordinates

Below is my code for picturebox in c#. I cannot figure out a way to check if the click coordinates(x,y) are changed, and if they are changed, the value of circlesize should change to 20.

Misc: Theprogram is for concentric circles. circlesize 20 means that circles should start drawing again from a small size.

```
private void picCanvas_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Draw")
    {
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
            Pen pen = new Pen(color);
            pen.Width = 3;
            paper.DrawEllipse(pen, x1 - circleSize / 2, y1 - circleSize / 2, circleSize, circleSize);

            circleSize += 10; // increase size here
            count += 1;
            MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
            Point coordinates = me.Location;
            x = me.X;
            y = me.Y;
    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Change Location")
    {

        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        Point coordinates = me.Location;
        x = me.X;
        y = me.Y;
        for (; i <= 0; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
                Pen pen = new Pen(color);
                pen.Width = 3;
                paper.DrawEllipse(pen, x - circleSize / 2, y - circleSize / 2, circleSize, circleSize);

                circleSize += 10; // increase size here
                a = 15;
            }
        }
        if (a == 15)
        {
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
            Pen pen = new Pen(color);
            pen.Width = 3;
            paper.DrawEllipse(pen, x - circleSize / 2, y - circleSize / 2, circleSize, circleSize);

            circleSize += 10; // increase size here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define two variable outside the scope of your `picCanvas_Click_1` function like `prevX` and `prevY`.

then before exiting `picCanvas_Click_1` (on last line for example) set them like

```
prevX = x;
prevY = y;
```

then check if they are changed or not in `picCanvas_Click_1` and do what you want like this

```
if (prevX != x || prevY != y)
{
  //do what you want
}
```